# ERROR: “/app/etc/” must exist for proper tool work magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, error, patches

I am trying to install the newly release security patch for magento 1.9. I am working on Ubuntu system.

and I am getting the following error.

> ERROR: "/app/etc/" must exist for proper tool work.

I am running php code.

```
<?php
    print("<PRE>");
    passthru("/bin/bash PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.2.2_v1-2016-01-20-04-35-33.sh");
    print("</PRE>");
    echo "Done";
?>
```

Can anyone tell me what is the exact issue and how it could be fixed.

Comment: But solution is different ..i have install patch using php code ...prince

Comment: are you sure you are running from Magento root this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Ubuntu System , you can directly run security patch file using

> ./PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.2.2_v1-2016-01-20-04-35-33.sh

And for the error you are getting it is due the line number 67 ( almost all patch files)

> CURRENT_DIR=`$PWD_BIN`/

Which fetches the current directory path and sets in very next line

> APP_ETC_DIR=`echo "$CURRENT_DIR""app/etc/"`

So your script is not able to get that `CURRENT_DIR` variable .

If you still wish to run the patch via php code you can update the patch file with absolute path of the directory like below (on line 67)

```
CURRENT_DIR="/d/username/projects/mypoject/"
```

and then run the PHP code , it should work

**Make sure that you patch file is in the root directory of magento**

Comment: yes i sure patch file in root directory

Comment: my current path is  CURRENT_DIR="/html/PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.2.2_v1-2016-01-20-04-35-33.sh"

Comment: its right or not plz check

Comment: No that's relative path , give the absolute patch

Comment: it should be like '/var/www/html/vishwas/Myproject'

Comment: successfully message display but not apply patch  CURRENT_DIR='/chroot/home/tahoorau/tahoora.com/html/'
APP_ETC_DIR=`echo "$CURRENT_DIR""app/etc/"`
APPLIED_PATCHES_LIST_FILE=`echo "$APP_ETC_DIR""applied.patches.list"`

Comment: not print patch on app/etc/applied.patches.list

Comment: It should be there , David ... rather than running via script why are you directly executing it ? these steps are usually for windows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63150/discussion-between-david-and-vishwas-bhatnagar).